# Handle LinkedIn accesstoken expiring after every 25 requests

Tags: java

My application registers user only once into my app. The application recieves feeds from LinkedIn when a Cron job runs. If the job tries to access a particular user more than 25 times per a day the job recieves an error like accesstoken expired. To solve this I have gone for solutions where I reauthorize the user. This should happen at server side to end my trouble. Does anyone have an Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Just set a `counter` for the number of times the jub is running and when the `counter` reaches `24` create a new auto access token, you can actually use this to verify if the user is actually using the system by asking the user to re login instead of servelet side auto logging in.